# default value of form in Symfony

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

To make a dafault value of select in my form I do like that :

```
   $def_volume = array(-1=>"Please select a volume");
   $def_issue = array(-1=>"Please select issue");

   $volumes = array_merge($def_volume,IssuePeer::getAllVolumesForListChoices());
   $issues = array_merge($def_issue,IssuePeer::getAllIssuesForListChoices());

   $this->setWidgets(array(
  'keyword'    => new sfWidgetFormInput(),
  'volume' => new sfWidgetFormSelect(array('choices' => $volumes)),
  'issue' => new sfWidgetFormSelect(array('choices' => $issues)),
));

   $this->setValidators(array(
  'keyword'    => new sfValidatorString(array('required' => true)),
  'volume' => new sfValidatorChoice(array('choices' => array_keys(IssuePeer::getAllVolumesForListChoices()))),
  'issue' => new sfValidatorChoice(array('choices' => array_keys(IssuePeer::getAllIssuesForListChoices()))),
));
```

the output :

```
<select id="filterSearch_volume" name="filterSearch[volume]">
<option value="0">Please select a volume</option>
....
</select>
```

but I hope to have the output like this :

```
<select id="filterSearch_volume" name="filterSearch[volume]">
<option value="">Please select a volume</option>
....
</select>
```

If you remark the value of the first value is `value="0"` but I hope that return me "null" like this `value=""`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
$def_volume = array('' => "Please select a volume");
```

That seems to work for me.

Comment: Why it didn't work? I tried on Sf 1.4.20 and it worked. The form sent an empty value.

Comment: yes the output of form in browser give me '<option value="">Please select a volume</option>' but when I click submit the form is invalid,the code stop here 'if ($this->form->isValid())' that mean the form is invalid?

Comment: Michal's technique is right. If the form's not valid it's because of some other reason. But Michal's answer is how you add a default value to a choice widget. 
You can't send a null value in a form. NULL is interpreted by PHP.

You shouldn't downvote people who are trying to help you Nll.

Comment: You will send an empty value (which of course is not null, but can be used in a similar way). @Nll the form does not pass the validation because in the validator you do not allow an empty value (note that sending an empty value does not equal sending nothing!).

Comment: @antony you are wrong too,because I'm not stupid to not test in the first time this solution,anyone will  try this,but it dosn't work and it give invalid form error and I'm sure the code of my form is correct.Because I send an array with an empty index that mean an array with index=null!Also when I change  null with -1 my form works fine...

Comment: @Nll please remember that `an empty index` and `null` is not the same. I showed you how you can send an empty value from the form. Me and @antony have pointed out why the empty value does not validate. If it's not what you wanted then I must have misunderstood your question.  Sorry.

Comment: @MichalTrojanowski It's different I'm ok but in both cases it's an invalid index for array,but the solution works just on the client side and it give me the list but after submitting the form not accept it ans it's normal an array without index,do you undestand me,the proof that when I change the index to -1 or a valid index the form works very fine....

Answer (score 1):

$this->widgetSchema['employee_id']->setOption('add_empty', 'Please choose a Employee');